# Short URL or Tiny urls in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, zoo

Someone help me know how I can have urls random for joomla sef in service?
I would like joomla or any component would generate urls like this:

mysite.com.br/f4f9o3

mysite.com.br/dsr9c2

mysite.com.br/fs39hl

Does anyone know any component or plugin to do this?

I would be happy if I could only have a Zoo Article ID...

mysite.com.br/145

Answer (score 1):

Check the collection of these extensions [here](https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/short-url). We haven't used any of them, but I suspect the CM Short URL would do exactly what you want.